# Where did my disk space go and why can't I analyze it?

Tags: storage

I am using ZorinOS lite mainly for rclone. The PC mainly hast the job to copy/ sync Files from one Cloud to another. Also a few very important business applications as the tabletop simulator for example are installed.

Now I See that my 240GB SSD is already almost full. Using `sudo baobab` I can see that most space is taken Up by the `/home/pc` directory. But I can not analyze much further. I could imagine that rclone has something to do with my problem but I can't seem to get any more information.

Here ist the result of the `sudo baobab` command:
[image]

Also using `sudo du -h /home/pc | sort -hr | head` did not give me any useful information about where the majority of my disk space has gone.

[image]

Now I would like to know what ist the exact problem and how to solve it (delete temporary Files (maybe created by rclone?)).

Thanks in advance for any help. I am not very experienced in Linux systems so easy understandable answers are appreciated.

Edit: Using the command `ls -la /home/pc` I am getting the following Output:
[image]

Comment: This looks like the lion's share is taken by simple files in the /home/pc directory, as its subdirectories consume only a small fraction. What does `ls -la /home/pc` say?

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. I have just added a Screenshot of the output of your command. I am not sure If the last row indicates that a lot of storage ist taken up by .xsession-errors which I am also not sure about what it actually means.

Comment: I have actually found the file in the directory and it takes over 180GB of my space.  Can I delete it?

Comment: Yes, but look into it first to analyze which programs you execute create this insane amount of error messages. You may do so after deleting the file and restarting the X server so you have a manageable file size. But OTOH, it may be interesting to see since when errors started to appear.